# Нужно перебрать циклом числа от 10 до 300 и вывести на экран те числа, сумма двух первых цифр которых будет равна 7

Tags: javascript, циклы

Хотел сделать так, но не получается

```
for (let i = 10; i <= 300; i++) {

    let str = String(i); 

    if (str[0] + str[1] === '7') {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы складываете строки '1' + '2' = '12' вот правильный код:

```
for (let i = 10; i <= 300; i++) {

    let str = String(i); 

    if (parseInt(str[0]) + parseInt(str[1]) === 7) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: при запуске этого кода отсчет идет с 70, но разве не должен идти с 16? и далее 25, 34 и тд

Comment: @Aiden Исправил. Извиняюсь показалось что там только 3-х значные числа.